# Не совместимы Foundation 6 & jQuery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, foundation

Подскажите почему у меня не совместимы `jquery 3` и `foundation 6`. Кто то говорит что они не совместимы, кто то говорит что нет поддержки. Кто знает и работает с этим?

Вот ссылка на такой же пример, только `jquery 1` все работает [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/vwtxushw/)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.js"></script>

<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed='true'>
    <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        Panel 3. Lorem ipsum dolor
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/vwtxushw/) версия `jquery.1.12.0` у вас 3, если поменять то у вас тоже работает все.

Comment: Я в курсе, по этому и добавил ссылку на работающий пример. Я хочу использовать 3 версию. Если они не совместимы, хочу понять почему, и где об этом почитать. И зачем мне две версии `jquery` в проекте из-за `foundation 6`

Comment: Обратная совместимость с работающими компонентами, обычная причина держать несколько версий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того как `jQuery 3` перестал поддерживать функцию `load` у `foundation` отвалилось пару компонентов. Фикс пришел после версии `6.4.*`

[Если интересно почитать](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/8923)

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>


<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed='true'>
  <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      Panel 3. Lorem ipsum dolor
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: блин, увидел бы ваш ответ, не парился бы вообще, зато разобрался в вопросе :)

Comment: @Pavel зато разобрались :)

Comment: Спасибо, долго искал ответ

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка спровоцирована `$(window).load()` функцией в `foundation.js`

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated
```

Дело в том что функцию в foundation поправили только начиная с 6.2.4.
Так же в конце должно вызываться `jQuery(document).foundation();`

```html
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed='true'>
    <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
        <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
            Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
        <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
            Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
        <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
            Panel 3. Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.4/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).foundation();
</script>
```